# Deserialize Xml with RestSharp

Tags: restsharp

I'm having problems getting RestSharp to deserialize some XML

this is a sample of the xml

```
<data xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <parameters xmlns="">
    <query-strings>
      <query-string value="testValue"></query-string>
    </query-strings>
    <sources>
      <source id="database"></source>
    </sources>
  </parameters>
  <objects>
    <object xmlns="" type="testType">
      <source id="database"></source>      
    </object>
    <object xmlns="" type="testType">
      <source id="database2"></source>
    </object>
    <object xmlns="" type="testType">
      <source id="database3"></source>
    </object>
  </objects>
</data>
```

Below is the Class that I'm trying to deserialize to

```
    public class Data
    {
        public Parameter Parameters { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parameter
    {
        public string InverseLookup { get; set; }

        public string TypeFilters { get; set; }

        public List<QueryString> QueryStrings { get; set; }

        public List<Source> Sources { get; set; }

        public List<Item> objects { get; set; }
    }

    public class QueryString
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public Source Source { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem that I have is the objects element, I just can't seem to get this to deserialize. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to have been between the Keyboard and Chair. (aka I'm an idiot.)

```
public class Data
{
    public Parameter Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

Should have been

```
public class Data
{
    public Parameter Parameters { get; set; }

    Public List<Item> Objects {get; set; }
}
```